# Poltergeist/Capybara test unable to find CSS intermittently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using Capybara and Poltergeist and cannot for the life of me get all my tests to consistently pass. I have this one issue in particular with a date selector. It should be really simple - user clicks on input, out puts a selection of months (first image). A month is then clicked, and then a day selection appears (second image), on which a day of the month is selected.

[image: first image]
[image: second image]

Now, my code looks as follows:

```
all(:css, 'input.from_date').last.click

expect(page).to have_css(".datepicker-months")
within(:css, '.datepicker-months') { find('.month', :text => 'Jun',  match: :first).click  }
expect(page).not_to have_css(".datepicker-months")

expect(page).to have_css(".datepicker-days")
within(:css, '.datepicker-days') { find('.day', :text => work[:start_date].stamp('31').to_i.to_s,  match: :first).click  } #.to_i.to_s used to remove leading zeros
page.assert_no_selector('.datepicker-days')
```

Sometimes it passes, but most of the time it says:

```
expected to find css ".datepicker-days" but there were no matches
```

or

```
expected not to find css ".datepicker-months", found 1 match: "« 2015 » JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
```

If I try and debug this by calling binding.pry, I can run the commands step by step in the console and it works perfectly. My timeout is set to more than enough (i think). Any ideas why this test fails intermittently?

My config:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

Capybara.default_wait_time = 60
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|

Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
    timeout: 60,
    js_errors: false, 
    phantomjs_logger: File.open("log/phantomjs.log", "a")})
end
```

**UPDATE:**

When adding sleep(0.5) after every step in the process, it passes each and every time. This is bad practice and I'm supposed to be able to write tests without doing this. :/

Comment: Did you eventually find any better way of dealing with this? I've tried triggering custom jQuery events to listen to using `page.execute_script` but it's still not very consistent.

Comment: Not really no. If there are JS methods in a library to trigger events, I just use that. Idea is that the functionality is already well tested in the library, so it shouldn't have to be tested again.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I run into these inconsistencies, I try to find other things to assert against so that you don't have to count on sleep.

If there are any sort of animations that start/stop, you can try to assert against those.

You can also try to be more specific in your current expectation, since it seems like you had no trouble clicking on the object you found

```
expect(page).not_to have_css('.datepicker-months .month', :text => 'Jun')
```

If any of that gets you any farther let us know.

Comment: Thanks, this does work for my one calendar, but doing it on another calendar returns false. So, calling `expect(page).to have_css(".calendar.right", :visible => true)` wil return `true`, but when hiding the element, `expect(page).not_to have_css(".calendar.right", :visible => true)` returns `false` even though the element is clearly not visible.